# File permissions not matching allowed operations...?

Tags: centos, permissions, ext4, selinux

I have been having several issues with a CentOS 9 VM related to file permissions.  I've never had this much trouble before, and I'm wondering if it has something to do with the security options and file systems I selected during install (GUI STIG and ext4).

### Example issue 1:

Two python files in the same directory, with the same permissions displayed by ls and stat

```
$ls -al config.py run_app.py
-rwx------. 1 myuser myuser 20K Aug  4 19:33 config.py
-rwx------. 1 myuser myuser 50K Jul  8 10:51 run_app.py
```

```
$stat config.py run_app.py
  File: config.py
  Size: 19873           Blocks: 40         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd05h/64773d    Inode: 1971283     Links: 1
Access: (0700/-rwx------)  Uid: ( 1000/myuser)   Gid: ( 1000/myuser)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
  File: run_app.py
  Size: 51016           Blocks: 104        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd05h/64773d    Inode: 1969096     Links: 1
Access: (0700/-rwx------)  Uid: ( 1000/myuser)   Gid: ( 1000/myuser)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
```

But lsattr doesn't work right:

```
$lsattr config.py run_app.py
--------------e------- config.py
lsattr: Operation not permitted While reading flags on run_app.py
$sudo lsattr run_app.py
--------------e------- run_app.py
```

I also cannot cat/edit/run run_app.py.  While all three operations work just fine on config.py.  Doing anything with run_app.py requires sudo/root.

### Example issue 2:

I cannot install python packages into a virtual environment, but I can install them to the local user environment.

```
myuser@COS9-VM:~/sandbox
$python3 -m venv myvenv

myuser@COS9-VM:~/sandbox
$. myvenv/bin/activate

(myvenv) myuser@COS9-VM:~/sandbox
$python3 -m pip install pyyaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/myuser/sandbox/myvenv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
  File "/home/myuser/sandbox/myvenv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/home/myuser/sandbox/myvenv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/home/myuser/sandbox/myvenv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/home/myuser/sandbox/myvenv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "/home/myuser/sandbox/myvenv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "/home/myuser/sandbox/myvenv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/configuration.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import (
  File "/home/myuser/sandbox/myvenv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/exceptions.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.pkg_resources import Distribution
  File "/home/myuser/sandbox/myvenv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import appdirs
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 982, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1039, in get_data
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/home/myuser/sandbox/myvenv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/appdirs.py'

(myvenv) myuser@COS9-VM:~/sandbox
$deactivate

myuser@COS9-VM:~/sandbox
$python3 -m pip install pyyaml
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pyyaml
  Using cached PyYAML-6.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (661 kB)
Installing collected packages: pyyaml
  WARNING: Value for scheme.platlib does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10151>
  distutils: /home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
  sysconfig: /home/myuser/.local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages
  WARNING: Additional context:
  user = True
  home = None
  root = None
  prefix = None
Successfully installed pyyaml-6.0
```

I am out of ideas...  What am I missing?

Comment: Doe anyone have a thought?  I'm up for trying some things and providing results.  I jsut ran into another issue.  I tried to install pygments (```python3 -m pip install pygments```) and it gave an error about the ~/.local/bin/pygments file.  The file was created, it has all of the permissions I would expect (read and execute), but I cannot execute it without being root.  I have used strace on these and I'm running into the file itself throwing EPERM from execve.  I'm also confused by my ```/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages``` not being readable or executable by normal users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After scouring the internet, I have an answer.  Of course the answer was on Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange already ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61672883/how-to-fix-the-weird-error-operation-not-permitted)), but it took me days to track it down.

My VM was running [`fapolicyd`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/assembly_blocking-and-allowing-applications-using-fapolicyd_security-hardening) as part of the STIG compliance configuration I enabled at installation.  This daemon inserts itself via hooks in the file permissions decision making process.  It has rules files that by default disable access to certain executable files in certain non-system binary/executable directories.  It does this based off its determination of the MIME type of the file as far as I can tell.  In my example `config.py` had no shebang, whereas `run_app.py` does.  This was enough to get the latter classified as `text/x-python`, while leaving the former alone.

Once I stopped/disabled the `fapolicyd` service, I was able to use files according to their displayed permissions/ACLs.